# Как передать id объекта в view при ajax запросе?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Имеется вопрос, под ним форма для добавления комментариев. Пробую реализовать через AJAX. Не знаю передать id текущего поста получить id поста, к которому добавляется ответ.

**models.py:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Text', max_length=100, required=True, min_length=2)
    question = forms.IntegerField(label='Text Answer', widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
def question_details(request, id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=int(id))
    form = AnswerForm(initial={'question': question.id})
    return render(request, 'question/question.html', {'question':  question,
                                         'form': form,
                                         'answers': question.answer_set.all(),
                                          'username': request.user,
                                         'tags': get_all_tags(),
                                                  })


def add_answer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer_text = request.POST.get('text')
        response_data = {}

        answer = Answer(text=answer_text, author=request.user, question= ???)
        answer.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['answerpk'] = answer.pk
        response_data['text'] = answer.text
        response_data['author'] = answer.author.username

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
    )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
 ...
    url(r'^question/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.question_details, name='question'
    url(r'^add-answer/$', views.add_answer, name='adding new answer via ajax requests'),),
    ....
```

**main.js**

```
....
$('#answer-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submitted!");
        add_comment();
    });


    function add_comment() {
    console.log("create post is working!");// sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "add-answer/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { text : $('#id_text').val() }, // data sent with the post request
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

1.Добавил новый атрибут в шаблон **data-q-id**:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-q-id="{{ question.id }}" id="sub-btn">Add</button>
```

2. В js получил его через **attr** и передал в функцию:

```
...
var question_id;
    question_id = $('#sub-btn').attr('data-q-id');
    event.preventDefault();
    add_comment(question_id);
...
```